# How to add text to end of link to single product page in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, slug

I am working on a project in Woocommerce. The link structure (slug) on the single product page is the direct product name. For example, if the product name is "x brand computer" link: [www.example.com/x-brand-computer-link](http://www.example.com/x-brand-computer-link)

What I want to do is to always add a new text "at the end of the link" on the single product page.
For example, like abc
[www.example.com/x-brand-computer-link-abc](http://www.example.com/x-brand-computer-link-abc)

I found many example solutions for Prefix. However, I couldn't find an example of "for end of link". What's more, I couldn't find any examples of a single product page. I would be very grateful if someone could guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

Sample code, has to be tested and refined:

```
// get all posts
$posts = get_posts( array (  'numberposts' => -1 ) );

foreach ( $posts as $post )
{
    // check the slug and run an update if necessary 
    $new_slug = sanitize_title( $post->post_title );
    if ( $post->post_name != $new_slug )
    {
        wp_update_post(
            array (
                'ID'        => $post->ID,
                'post_name' => $new_slug
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend using save_post hook and update only the current post. I dont see the point of looping all posts everytime.

Comment: Then you can just edit slug and submit https://prnt.sc/4wiAVt94sDcL

Comment: OP didnt mention generating from title but okay...